# file csv: how can I count occourrences of value based on other column value with python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have a .csv file (600 lines) with some field: commit id, smell type and more.

I would count the occourrences of each type of smell for each commit id.

example of output i wouuld:

```
   commit dfbu3u4498fbbefi: [dense structure :1, cyclic dependency:4, unstable dependency: 67, feature concentration: 6, god component: 8]
  commit  bifueifyuwefbvwr: [dense structure :34, cyclic dependency:43, unstable dependency: 97, feature concentration: 43, god component: 10]
```

I tried with this but i think I need another loop (maybe?)
Sorry, I never used Python before

```
import csv
import collections

smell = collections.Counter()


with open('Ref.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')

    for row in reader:

        smell[row[0]] += 1

print (smell.most_common(5))

OUTPUT:

[('9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920', 96), ('6431099fe7d5d90da678a78051f12894da82c68d', 96), ('44fdfa7ea93c15bb116a25e0675d98469deafaa6', 96), ('b2c40612a2c60685555f35af71f5801391a58b4b', 96), ('aa6cbb78cca17a9de339b2d060c00352e8beedde', 96)]

or if i change row index to 2 i got

[('Unstable Dependency', 315), ('Feature Concentration', 238), ('God Component', 84), ('Cyclic Dependency', 28), ('Dense Structure', 7)]
```

Comment: kindly use this as a guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What part are you struggling with?

Comment: `df.groupby(['commit_id', 'smell']).count()`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code and explain in detail you comment? Please refer to the documentation that @sammywemmy mentioned.

Comment: @Iv10 thank you, I edited the question

Comment: @Marat thank you, i don't know why but i have some issue with groupby function

Comment: @daisy you need to use it on a pandas dataframe. `df = pd.read_csv('Ref.csv')` to create one

Comment: @Marat yes, i alredy did this. i installed panda 0.22 and it works, but when i try to groupby i got errors on module.

Comment: Please don't share information as images unless absolutely necessary, which isn't the case here. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe definition
df = pd.read_csv('Ref.csv', sep=';')

# Group and get the count values.

df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['commit', 'smell']).size()
```

`df_grouped` is now a `pandas.series`, if you want it to be a `dataframe` again you should do this:

```
df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index()
df_grouped = df_grouped.rename(columns={0: "counts"})
```

I highly recommend you to have a look at the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

Comment: i tried but failed :( I got this `runfile('C:/Users/daisy/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/daisy/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-fbb006e8e2f7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/daisy/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/daisy/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace) `

Comment: `File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/daisy/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py", line 8, in <module>
    df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['commit', 'smell']).size()

  File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7894, in groupby
    **kwargs`

Comment: `File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2522, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 391, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated,

  File "C:\Users\daisy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 621, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'commit' `

Comment: Sorry I was using capital letters for the column names. I've edited my answer

Comment: Maybe your columns have a different name, can you show me the output of `df.head()`

Comment: this is the output of df.head() `                                commit;package;smell
0  9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920;<All ...
1  9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920;org.j...
2  9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920;org.j...
3  9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920;org.j...
4  9b0dd5dc979bd490ae34f6d790c466b47c84c920;org.j...`

Comment: Try adding ` sep=';' ` when reading the csv file. If this doesnt work, is there a way you can share the file with me so I can test it by myself?